# The installation directory "/usr/local/bin" is not writable - How to fix this? I am trying to install the composer globally

Tags: javascript, php, composer-php, laravel-5.1

ERROR message while trying to setup Composer:
[image: ERROR message while trying to setup Composer]

```
192:~ biancalouisedairo$  php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
192:~ biancalouisedairo$ php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '93b54496392c062774670ac18b134c3b3a95e5a5e5c8f1a9f115f203b75bf9a129d5daa8ba6a13e2cc8a1da0806388a8') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
Installer verified
192:~ biancalouisedairo$ php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin
All settings correct for using Composer
The installation directory "/usr/local/bin" is not writable
192:~ biancalouisedairo$
```

Comment: Use `sudo` then.

Comment: Ive tried but it says File exists.

Answer (score 2):

Use **sudo** before your command

like this `sudo php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 1):

This will remove any already-installed Composer and install it correctly for you:

```
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/composer
EXPECTED_SIGNATURE=$(curl -s https://composer.github.io/installer.sig)
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
ACTUAL_SIGNATURE=$(php -r "echo hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php');")

if [ "$EXPECTED_SIGNATURE" == "$ACTUAL_SIGNATURE" ]
then
    php composer-setup.php --quiet
    rm composer-setup.php
    sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
    sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/composer
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Just incase, don't forget to `cd` (cd and space) to your home/root before running the installation commands from any of the upvoted or approved answers

```
cd
```

Answer (score 0):

First make a folder. Than open command prompt or git bash on that folder  than run all the command one by one.

> mkdir phpproject

> cd phpproject

**than run all commands one by one**

> php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"

> php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '55ce33d7678c5a611085589f1f3ddf8b3c52d662cd01d4ba75c0ee0459970c2200a51f492d557530c71c15d8dba01eae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
> Installer verified

> php composer-setup.php

**output**

> All settings correct for using Composer
> Downloading...

Composer (version 2.3.10) successfully installed to: C:\Users\Rabbil khan\Deskto
p\phpproject\composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar

... than just simply run --  ***php composer.phar***

Answer (score -2):

Because you are not root user
use sudo -i to give p